# Access to other custom php pages

Tags: navigation, external-scripts

I am new to Drupal, so please bare with me. I have a Drupal site that is working fine. Now what I want to do is allow access to folder which contains some custom php script.

I tried to put the folder in the `/sites/default/files/` but it didn't work. I found a question on it  [Extending Drupal Functionality to Custom PHP Page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35427/extending-drupal-functionality-to-custom-php-page) but not able to add Drupal functionality on this page. I just want to access that folder and its content.

So please any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please use correct grammar, question marks etc. Split your text into paragraphs. Also, I think your tag choice is bad, but I'm not sure I understood you enough to retag on my own.

Comment: Please avoid using vague terms like "allow access" and "doesn't work". It's just unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking just for an `include (path/to/script);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default path or root directory of any Drupal site is the same directory/folder which contains the site itself. ie. Same directory which houses the "sites" directory. If I put a php file there called "my_code.php", any reference to the file will be seen by everything as default. Its when other directories are created and the file placed there which make a file's location more specfic. So if I'm in a php file in another directory and I put in a statement like:

`include 'my_code.php';`

Drupal will start by looking in its default root directory. If I create a directory there called "my_php_files" and put the "my_code.php" file inside, then my reference to include that file would be:

`include 'my_php_files/my_code.php';`

Default permissions are normally 755 for directories and 644 for files.